# Open a jstree in a jquery dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-dialog, jstree

I've looked for every possible example, but couldn't find a complete one. I'm new to jQuery and javascript in general - I'm a backend developer. I'm trying to display the html results of an ajax call inside a jstree in a dialog box, and don't have the first clue what I'm doing. This is what I've come up with so far - can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? (I had to retype this vs copy/paste, so there may be some minor typos).

```
success: function(data) {
    $.getScript("js/jquery/jquery.jstree.js", function() {
        var $genericDialog = $("#genericDialog")
        $genericDialog.jstree({"html_data":data});
        $genericDialog.dialog({
            title: "ASDF",
            modal: true,
            width: 450,
            height: 700,
            buttons: {
                "OK": function() {
                         $genericDialog.dialog("close");
                     }
            }
        });
    });
},
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: The data doesn't display. The dialog box pops up, but there's no data.

Comment: Most probably the problem is with your "data". What kind of data is returned from the backend ? Can you paste the data in your question ?

Comment: The data is an unordered list. Pretty standard. Unfortunately, it's on a different network and I can't copy and paste it, but it's straightforward <ul><li> stuff. So there's nothing wrong with the javascript I have above?

Comment: Use `Chrome` or `Firefox with Firebug` to capture the ajax request on the `Network` tab in `Chrome Developer Tools` or `Firebug`  and check the server response. If it is ok try to use `console.log` or step-by-step execution to ensure your code is executing as you expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From there documentation

```
 "html_data" : {
        "data" : "<li id='root'><a href='#'>Root node</a><ul><li><a href='#'>Child node</a></li></ul></li>"
    },
```

So make sure that the object you are passing to "html_data" is in the above format. i.e your 'data' should be an object with "data" as its property.

Other than that, I don't see any problems with your code.

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/STA3c/7/

I have used your code. It seems to be working. Check if all the correct javascript files are loaded properly.

Comment: Well, I tried to use your example exactly and hardcode the html data as you have it, and I still don't get a display in the dialog box.

Comment: Why don't you first check if the data is populated in 'genericDialog' div. If it does, then use a dialog.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your suggestion. I'm hard-coding the data as in your example from the documentation. I can tell you if I bypass jstree, and open the data directly in the dialog box it's there.

Comment: You are absoulely right, it does display. Turns out the style was so dark I couldn't see the tree! THANKS A LOT for your help.