# jsTree: open "add folder" (or any right-click option) with modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jstree

I inherited a somewhat-spaghetti coded upload program, and it uses jsTree to list the files that were uploaded. When you right-click jsTree, you get an option box with some options (Upload File, Add Folder, Delete Folder, etc.) These lead to separate pages. I was wondering if it's possible that when you click those options, such as Add Folder, it would trigger a modal pop-up rather than go to a separate page?

Here's the code I am trying to work with:

```
function buildTreeViewContextMenu(node)
{
    var items = {};
    if ($(node).attr('id') == 'trash')
    {
        <?php if($totalTrash > 0): ?>
        var items = {
            "Empty": {
                "label": "<?php echo t('empty_trash', 'Empty Trash'); ?>",
                "action": function(obj) {
                    confirmEmptyTrash();
                }
            }
        };
        <?php endif; ?>
    }
    else if ($(node).attr('id') == '-1')
    {
        var items = {
            "Upload": {
                "label": "<?php echo t('upload_files', 'Upload Files'); ?>",
                "separator_after": true,
                "action": function(obj) {

                    window.location='/';
                }
            },

            "Add": {
                "label": "<?php echo t('add_folder', 'Add Folder'); ?>",
                "action": function(obj) {                       
                    window.location='/view/folder/add?p='+obj.attr("id"); // this part I want to convert to a modal
                }
            }
        };

    }
```

And for example, here is the modal for "Add Folder":

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="modalAddFolder" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalAddFolder" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Folder</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <?php require_once("folder/add.php"); ?>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Add Folder modal -->
    </div>
    <!-- /modal -->
```

I've tried working with [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352929/open-a-jstree-in-a-jquery-dialog-box) but have not been able to integrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out - hope this helps someone else. It was much simpler than I thought:

You can just trigger the modal with some jQuery (I don't know why I didn't think I can't mix javascript / jQuery - maybe it's not good practice, but for right now, it works.)

```
 "Add": {
        "label": "<?php echo t('add_folder', 'Add Folder'); ?>",
         "action": function(obj) {
           $('#modalAddFolder').modal('show'); 
           }
          },
```

Unlike the window.location, this one doesn't initiate variables, but those can be easily attached when necessary.